# How to extract date and hour only from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have this column in MySQL table:

```
Date
2022-07-13 07:01:20
```

I want to extract this column to get this (the date and hour only):

```
2022-07-13 07
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

This date column is in the form of timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Apparently timestamp is a string so i can use substring.

Answer (score 0):

To select the date and hour from that format first you have to take the substring using `SUBSTRING()`
the convert to datetime format using  `STR_TO_DATE()`
you can take the specific date using `SELECT CONVERT(date, your_date_time);`
then extract the hour to add it in there  `SELECT HOUR()`
you can then convert back to a string or use it that way